# custom site template uploaded and activated in site solution gallery are not comming in custom template

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, sharepoint-foundation

i had recently migrated my web application from SharePoint 2010 to Sharepoint 2013.
One of my site are having custom site templates which are used to create Sub Sites.
now i can find those templates in Solution gallery in upgraded site in activated status but when i tried to create a sub site in the new site the custom templates are not showing.Am i missing somthing??
[image: Solution Gallery showing KM TEMPLATE 7 OCT 2013]

Answer (score 2):

you missed some steps to enable the custom site templates. You have to add the custom site templates in page layouts and site templates settings. To enable that, go to the site settings -> select Page Layouts and Site Templates(under Look and Feel section) -> in subsite templates section, select subsites can only use the following site templates option and you can select the site templates you want to use.

Comment: i followed your steps but i cant find these custom templates under page layouts and site templates.

Comment: you should double check your features have activated yet

Comment: try activating Publishing infrastructure feature

Answer (score 1):

Check whether you have limited what templates were available in the site via the /_layouts/AreaTemplateSettings.aspx page (typically only available in a publishing site). You might want to check to make sure that all templates are available for creating sites.

Also check with the publishing feature as it should be activated while creating template sub-site.