# Custom site template not showing up in list when creating new site

Tags: 2013, 2010, site-collection, upgrade, template

I upgraded a site collection from 2010 to 2013.

There is a site template called "My Site Template" which shows up in solution gallery (in Site Settings) in both 2010 and 2013. I can also activate and deactivate it in 2013.

I have also deactivated and reactivated same site collection features in 2013 that are in 2010.

This template is showing up in "Custom" tab when you try to create a new site in 2010. But the same template is not showing up in "Custom" tab in 2013 (when creating new site)

In fact "Custom" tab is not even there in 2013.

I also have a code where I am reading that template. When looping, I can see that template in 2010 but same template is not coming up in 2013.

```
SPWebTemplateCollection templates = site.GetWebTemplates(1033);

foreach (SPWebTemplate template in templates)
{

}
```

I am stuck in this issue for the past 2 days and read many solutions but none are working.

Here's another person facing same issue but no luck.

[custom site template uploaded and activated in site solution gallery are not comming in custom template](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/98722/custom-site-template-uploaded-and-activated-in-site-solution-gallery-are-not-com)

How do I make that template appear?

Comment: Do you have a site in your 2013 environment that is created using the 2010 template?

Comment: Yes could be. Because I upgraded this site collection from 2010. And this whole work was done by some other guy who has left the company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same situation when I did the migration from 2010 to 2013. After the upgrade, in my 2013 environment, I simply saved an existing site created from the 2010 template as a template and uploaded that to the solutions gallery.This way the template was available under the custom tab in my 2013 environment.

Comment: Taking a cue from your answer, here's what I did to solve the issue. I downloaded template from SP 2010 server which was in the form of .wsp. I renamed it to .cab and then extracted manifest.xml. In this file there is a property called "SharePointProductVersion" which was set to version "14.0.4762.1000". I went to CA of SP 2013 farm and in "Servers in farm" under "System Settings", noted down version and replaced it with that one. Then I remade .cab using MakeCab.exe utility and then renamed it to .wsp and uploaded in solutions gallery in SP 2013.

Comment: Excellent work! @FrankMartin